# ExtensionInstallForcelist policy issue since Chrome version 63.0.3239.84

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, active-directory, chromium, group-policy

I am deploying a WebExtension for Chrome via an ActiveDirectory domain.
The machines in this domain are not able to connect to the internet. Only websites hosted in the intranet are available.
Consequently I am using the ExtensionInstallForcelist policy for installing the WebExtension in Chrome (without uploading it to the Chrome Web Store).
In the intranet there exists a server, which is hosting the WebExtension (.crx file) and an update manifest XML file (which points to the .crx file).

With Chrome version 62.0.3202.94 everything is working. Once the policy is applied, the WebExtension is installed in Chrome. The WebExtension is force-installed, so that the user does not have to activate it manually.

But since Chrome version 63.0.3239.84 there occurs an issue. The WebExtension is installed, but deactivated immediately. Moreover I observed a weird behavior. After starting Chrome, the WebExtension is activated for a short moment, but then deactivated directly after. This happens several times until the behavior subsides. If Chrome is closed and restarted, this behavior is repeated. This behavior occurs on multiple devices and on machines in other domains.

I checked the url chrome://policy. The ExtensionInstallForcelist entry is correctly applied.

In the chrome_debug.log it seems that Chrome tries to check the WebExtension at some url, but the check fails. The issue occurs also for "version 63.0.3239.108" and "Version 64.0.3282.24 (official build) beta (64-bit)". With version 62.0.3202.94 on the same machine everything is working.

For better overview I will use the following substitutions in the extracts from the chrome_debug.log

```
{extensionID} : The ID of my WebExtension
{url_to_update_manifest} : The url which delivers the update manifest XML file
{value} : A value
```

Extracts from the chrome_debug.log:

```
VERBOSE1:content_hash_fetcher.cc(252)] Missing verified contents for {extensionID}, fetching...
VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(30)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=uc%26installsource%3Dsignature%26id%3D{extensionID}%26v%3D1.0.1
VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(30)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://{extensionID}/background.js
VERBOSE1:content_verify_job.cc(230)] job failed for {extensionID} background.js reason:1
VERBOSE1:content_verifier.cc(144)] VerifyFailed {extensionID} reason:1
VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context: [...]
VERBOSE1:content_hash_fetcher.cc(301)] URLFetchComplete for {extensionID} is_success:1 https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=uc%26installsource%3Dsignature%26id%3D{extensionID}%26v%3D1.0.1
VERBOSE1:content_verifier.cc(229)] OnFetchComplete {extensionID} success:0
WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(197)] Corruption detected in policy extension {extensionID} installed at: C:\Users\Testuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\{extensionID}\1.0.1_2
VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(30)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: http://{url_to_update_manifest}/?os=win&arch=x64&nacl_arch=x86-64&prod=chromecrx&prodchannel=&prodversion=63.0.3239.108&lang=de&acceptformat=crx2,crx3&x=id%3D{extensionID}%26v%3D0.0.0.0%26installsource%3Dreinstall%26uc
VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(30)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: http://{url_to_update_manifest}
VERBOSE1:pending_extension_manager.cc(305)] Extension id {extensionID} was entered for update more than once.  old location: 7  new location: 7  old version: invalid  new version: invalid
VERBOSE1:install_signer.cc(435)] Sending request: {"hash":"{value}=","ids":["{value}","{value}","{value}","{value}","{extensionID}","{value}","{value}"],"protocol_version":1}
VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(30)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/verify
VERBOSE1:install_signer.cc(460)] Got response: {"protocol_version":1,"invalid_ids":["{extensionID}"],"signature":"{value}==","expiry":"2018-03-13","pubkey_sha1_hash":"{value}"}
VERBOSE1:content_verify_job.cc(230)] job failed for {extensionID} background.js reason:1
VERBOSE1:content_verifier.cc(144)] VerifyFailed {extensionID} reason:1
```

I also looked into the changelog and the Chromium source code, but could not find the reason for this behavior.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/62.0.3202.94..63.0.3239.84?pretty=fuller&n=10000

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/browser/content_verifier.cc?sq=package:chromium&l=144

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining an update_url in the manifest.json solved the issue for me. The update_url does not need to be a real update_url. For example you can define http://localhost/123 as update_url.

The following sources helped me:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794219

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/install_verifier.cc?l=219&rcl=2c30e2d667b6790965fed75d19cc6b76be700265

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, Chrome detects a change in the extension so it tryes to update your extension from your 'local store' but also from the Chrome Web Store.

So You should check the update url used in your extension.

You could also try to repack your extension with Chrome 63.